# Select into xml from table in sql server with distinct id

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have table that contains three columns:

```
[ID],[Name],[Value]
```

My select for xml result:

```
DECLARE @xml XML    
SET @xml = (
       SELECT  
                ID
                ,[Name]
                ,[Value]
           FROM [CustomerDetails]
           WHERE ID = 1
      FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Customer')
       )    
     SELECT @xml
```

My select return xml with multiple ID properties:

```
<Customer>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>FirstName</Name>
  <Value>firstName</Value>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>LastName</Name>
  <Value>lastName</Value>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>Age</Name>
  <Value>20</Value>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Name>City</Name>
  <Value>London</Value>
</Customer>
```

I need next xml:

```
 <Customer>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>FirstName</Name>
      <Value>firstName</Value>  
      <Name>LastName</Name>
      <Value>lastName</Value>  
      <Name>Age</Name>
      <Value>20</Value>  
      <Name>City</Name>
      <Value>London</Value>
    </Customer>
```

How to return this kind of XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have shortened name of columns:

```
declare @id int = 1

select id, n, v from
(select @id id, null n, null v, 1 as rn from t
union
select null, n, v, 2 as rn from t
where id = @id
 ) t order by rn
for xml path(''), root('customer')
```

Output:

```
<customer><id>1</id><n>n1</n><v>v1</v><n>n2</n><v>v2</v><n>n3</n><v>v3</v></customer>
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/70ea0/4